# Starting and stopping piped processes with Supervisor

Tags: supervisord, pipe

I have a situation where I pipe the output of ffmpeg into a PHP script for some processing. I might have a few of these processes running at any given time and I figured to start and stop them I might use Supervisor.

However, I'm running into the problem where I can start a new process but where I can't successfully stop it. I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i http://mystream.com -v 0 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le - | php process.php
```

To make the "piping" work I use the following for the `command` in Supervisor:

```
[program:process]
command = /bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i http://mystream.com -v 0 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le - | php /home/me/process.php'
```

This seems to be working and starts the whole process just fine, however, when I stop the process using `supervisorctl`:

```
stop process
```

I see with an `ps aux` that the `ffmpeg` process is still running. The `php process.php` seems to have been killed though.

What is the correct way to start and stop a piped command with Supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

% sh -c 'your one-liner' 
I think this works

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer